# How do I print validation messages for form_for :post structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, form-for

I have something like

```
<div class="userInput">
    <%= form_for :scribble do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :scribble, cols: 65, rows: 4,:maxlength => 255%>
    <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

1)My Scribble model has min and max character length validation, now how do I print the error messages here. If it is an instance variable I know how to print, but this is a symbol.

2) This code is present in the `application.html.erb`. I am not able to understand how do I move it into a view of Scribble controller other than appliation. Problem is this form is not independent, it is a part of action index display of controller Scribbles,(and the form should be displayed always) and action index is already doing listing of scribbles.

Controller

```
  def index
    @scribbles = Scribble.order("scribbles.scribble DESC").all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @scribble = Scribble.new(profile_params)
    @scribble.likes =@scribble.dislikes =@scribble.shares=0; 
    @scribble.save
    @scribbles = Scribble.order("scribbles.scribble DESC").all
    render :index
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how i out-put any errors or validation messages:

**Controller:**

```
def create
    @scribble = Scribble.new(profile_params)
    @scribble.likes =@scribble.dislikes =@scribble.shares=0;

    if @scribble.save 
      flash[:notice] = "Scribble is successfully created"
      redirect_to root_url
    else #
      render 'index'
    end
 end
```

**Views:**
Create a partial to show error messages if any e.g `_error_messages.html.erb`

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <div class="alert callout text-center" data-closable>
        <p><strong>This form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, 'error') %>.</strong></p>
        <ul>
          <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
              <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
        <button class="close-button" aria-label="Dismiss alert" type="button" data-close>
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**Render errors:**
Now you can call `<%= render 'layouts/error_messages', object: @scribble %>` and put it anywhere in your views to render the errors validation. `note: the object is passed, so it can be re-use to any form.` credits to Hartl Tutorial.